# Git: Performing a diff between two stashes

Tags: git, diff

Is it possible with Git to perform a diff between two stashes?

For instance, I have the following stashes:

```
stash@{2}: On peformanceFix#3: 20170728T164841
stash@{3}: On peformanceFix#2: 20170727T073349
```

I want a diff between the two.

Comment: Should be able to simply do `git diff stash@{2} stash@{3}`

Comment: Also got the answer with one google search. It is the top search result for `git diff two stashes` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677736/git-diff-against-a-stash

Comment: The command from the first comment works, and in fact gives me the same output as the one in the accepted solution. However, the thread linked in the second comment is about a different question, and contains neither of these solutions.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As mentioned by *Confuzing* and *Per Quested Aronsson* in the comments, the simplest solution is:

```
git diff stash@{2} stash@{3}
```

It also works with the -p added, but that does not add much value.

```
git diff -p stash@{2} -p stash@{3}
```

Oddly, Git's documentation does not suggest to use twice the -p option.  I just tried it and found out it worked.

Comment: Seems to work without the -p option as well, at least in git version 2.16.2

Comment: For me, it gives an error `git.exe: The command parameter was already specified.` when I try to compare the stashes with `git diff stash@{0} stash@{1}`. What did I do wrong? I have the git version `git version 2.37.3.windows.1`

Comment: I get the same error as Kashif

Comment: I got the same in GitKraken terminal and PowerShell. Instead I tried in Command Prompt where it worked. I guess you have to give multiple parameters in another way in the Terminal/PowerShell